# How to disable DialogFragment transition animation when resuming the application?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

I have the following logic that sets a custom animation for my DialogFragment to slide in and out from the right hand screen in Kotlin.

```
dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_style
```

Everything is great, but when I go to my mobile phone's home screen and effectively placing my app into the background and then when I bring it back I see that the animation activates as well.

Is there a way to temporarily disable the animation whenever I reopen the application from the background and then restore the animation when the DialogFragment loads.

It looks weird in my opinion to see the DialogFragment transition in when I reopen the app, it looks better when there is no animation (default style)

I want the custom animation to apply only when I'm navigating between fragments in my app, but no animation when the fragment is resumed from a background state (paused?).

Answer (score 4):

I used `savedInstanceState` to check if the app is being reopened and set `windowEnterAnimation` to null. Here's my solution.

First, create two styles.

```
<style name="Animation.MyApp.CustomDialogFragment">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out</item>
</style>

<style name="Animation.MyApp.CustomDialogFragment.Restore">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then, override `onCreateDialog()` from DialogFragment.

```
open class CustomDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            dialog.window?.setWindowAnimations(
                R.style.Animation_MyApp_CustomDialogFragment
            )
        } else {
            dialog.window?.setWindowAnimations(
                R.style.Animation_MyApp_CustomDialogFragment_Restore
            )
        }

        return dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in the onCreateDialog because it isn't called after app backgrounded for a short time. I ended up saving a boolean indicator if the dialog fragment reaches onStop and then in onStart if the boolean is true I set the new style with the null animation and it works great.

Comment: @ItayFeldman why keeping boolean, when if onStop is called, onStart will be called as well? 

This will disable exit animation for the user, which is not something that I want.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your styles

```xml
<style name="Animation.App.FlushMessage" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_flush_message_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_flush_message_out</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Animation.App.FlushMessage.Exit" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_flush_message_out</item>
    </style>
```

2. Override onStart:

```kotlin
class YourDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {

  var setupAnim = false

  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    
    if (setupAnim) {
        requireDialog().window?.setWindowAnimations(R.style.Animation_App_FlushMessage_Exit)
    } else {
        setupAnim = true
        requireDialog().window?.setWindowAnimations(R.style.Animation_App_FlushMessage)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: you make my day. You are genius.